# Is it correct to use taxonomy_term_is_page() in this code?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, nodes

I am trying to get some content to show up when some conditions are verified: if I am on a certain page, the content will be shown; differently, the content is blank.
Everything looks correct; I just don't know if I am not using the correct function or something else is wrong.

```
<?php if (!taxonomy_term_is_page('18')): ?>
  <h5><a href="home/news">blah 1 News</a></h5>
<?php elseif (!taxonomy_term_is_page('28')): ?>
  <h5><a href="home/news">blah 2 News</a></h5>
<?php elseif (!taxonomy_term_is_page('29')): ?>
  <h5><a href="home/news">blah 3 News</a></h5>
<?php elseif (!taxonomy_term_is_page('30')): ?>
  <h5><a href="home/news">blah 4 News</a></h5>
<?php elseif (!taxonomy_term_is_page('81')): ?>
  <h5><a href="home/news">blah 5 News</a></h5>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This displays the results; however, when I am on one of the other terms the output doesn't change: it stays the same as the output for the taxonomy term with ID equal to 18.

My description for what I was trying to achieve has been changed; I am not trying to get anything shown based on any conditions. To put it in better words, I am trying to have the content shown; if I am on taxonomy/term/18, the content would show the else nothing would shown if I am on taxonomy/term/28 content shows and so on. It's simular to is_front_page function and you have content shown if you are on the front page, except these are taxonomy terms.

Comment: Why is there a "!" in the condition? Right now, you are saying if this is not the page for taxonomy term 18, display blah 1 news. You probably want to remove that...

Comment: when i remove it nothing displays what do you suggest i put instead?

Comment: Don't use taxonomy_term_is_page() in the first place :) See kiamlaluno's updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basing on the documentation of [taxonomy_term_is_page()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_is_page/7),  the function just checks if the current page is the page of the passed-in term. Looking at the code, the function verifies the path of the current page is "taxonomy/term/%term-id", and "%term-id" is the term ID of the taxonomy term passed as argument.

```
function taxonomy_term_is_page($term) {
  $page_term = menu_get_object('taxonomy_term', 2);
  return (!empty($page_term) ? $page_term->tid == $term->tid : FALSE);
}
```

You are passing to the function the wrong parameters; you should pass it a taxonomy term object.
The code you reported is calling the function as `taxonomy_term_is_page('28')`.

If you know the term ID for the taxonomy term, then you can use the following code:

```
<?php
  $page_term = menu_get_object('taxonomy_term', 2);
?>
<?php if (!empty($page_term)): ?>
  <?php if ($page_term->tid != 18): ?>
    <h5><a href="home/news">blah 1 News</a></h5>
  <?php elseif ($page_term->tid != 28): ?>
    <h5><a href="home/news">blah 2 News</a></h5>
  <?php elseif ($page_term->tid != 29)): ?>
    <h5><a href="home/news">blah 3 News</a></h5>
  <?php elseif ($page_term->tid != 30): ?>
    <h5><a href="home/news">blah 4 News</a></h5>
  <?php elseif ($page_term->tid != 81): ?>
    <h5><a href="home/news">blah 5 News</a></h5>
  <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: yes i saw that but i need the function to work from a view theme not from in the functions page thats why i did a if else statement.

Comment: @Jeremy Love See my updated answer.

Comment: its the same code?

Comment: @Jeremy Love `taxonomy_term_is_page()` is the function you are calling, but as you see the parameters you are passing are not correct; you should pass just a taxonomy term object to the function, not a string and an integer.

Comment: i updated the code

Comment: updated, im sorry if im being confusing im still learning the functions to this, and i appreciate you guys help

Comment: @Jeremy Love: No, you don't touch "2", that means it loads the third argument from the path as the term. You only touch the numbers below, like 18 and so on. The code *is* correct, try it :)

Comment: @Jeremy: Also, it is cleaner and the "Drupal way" to place logic like that in a preprocess function, save it in $variables['title'] for example, and in your template, just print $title.